# To display Text On Notify Icon Mouse Over

Tags: c#, notifyicon

How to display text on mouseover of notifyicon in c#.Since the ShowBalloonTip shows with respect to the timeout, how can i display the text on mouseover of the Notify Icon?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Text Property of NotifyIcon class is what you need](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.text%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

.Text is rendered as a tooltip when you hover over the icon.

```
public string Text { get; set; }
```